# Jira project automation (Issue type - Test)(Zephyr TestStep)

Tags: json, automation, jira, project, jira-zephyr

Maybe any one can help,
I am trying to create Project automation in Jira and using automation rule.
Condition in issue transitioned from one status to other then create a new task.

Everythin is working if I am creating new story, but I would like to create new Test issue.
But I am getting error that Zephyr Test Step is required (custom field xx) I can not choose this field from the list, is not visible, and I do not know how to use json window..

[image]

any one have ideas?

[image]

Comment: In the image provided, you have added a space in the field name `Zephyr Teststep` causing it to become `Zephyr Test Step`. This is not what the field is called, according to the error message, and thus is likely why the field isn't being set.

Comment: This won't fully fix your problem though, as you have written invalid JSON, and the field will likely require a more complex value than "red".